# How can I get HTTP RPC Server and client to work?

Tags: go, rpc

I am trying to send messages from client to server and back using the **exact** HTTP RPC server/client code given [here](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmfYeDhGH9bZzihBUDEQbCbTc5k5FZKURMUoUvfmc27BwL/rpc/go_rpc.html).

However, when I run the server, my command line becomes blank because the server starts listening using:

```
err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

In the client code, I need to get an argument from the command line for client to run:

```
serverAddress := os.Args[1]
```

However, this argument is not available because the server code makes my command line blank.

How can I get the server and client to work on the same command line window?

Comment: That is expected - the server will run until it is stopped (and needs to be running if the client is to communicate with it). Generally I would test it from a second window; if you need to do it from the same window then run the server as a background process (how you do this depends upon your OS; for linux add a ` &`after the command).

Comment: @Brits Thank you! However, when running from the second window, how is "serverAddress" suppose to get the os.Args[1]?

Comment: You pass it the address in via the command line (e.g. `client 127.0.0.1`). That's how [os.Args](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) gets populated (it has nothing to do with the server at that point).

Comment: Oh right. I will try this out. The "client" phrase you typed there is the go file where the client code is right?

Comment: I would generally [`go build`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) and then run the executable created (with the argument(s)). You can also use [`go run .`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)  (but that can sometimes act in unexpected ways because the executable is created/run in a temporary folder).